The evaluation of a portfolio using quadratic utility or CRRA?
Given a (selection of) multi-asset fund I am finding the expected utility using the historical returns distribution for a range of risk aversion parameters, in order to yield some form of rating, and I’d like to know if there’s a preferred utility function to use. The decision, at the moment, is between CRRA and quadratic utility.
It’s become apparent that CRRA is a more sound choice behaviourally than quadratic utility along with more flexibility over the returns distributions it’s applicable to, but of course comes with a slightly more involved calculation. To my understanding quadratic utility is best when combined with normal returns which most funds don’t have. But the majority of conversations on this were in reference to the asset allocation problem, is the superiority only relevant here or do the same drawbacks manifest in the evaluation of expected utilities too?
The real question is does anyone use quadratic utility; if so which use cases? Or is CRRA just the standard nowadays?
How far from the normal case do you need to stray before the issues with quadratic utility actually start to be problematic?

People who use an explict utility function most commonly use CRRA. Quadratic is  convenient (and popular w/ theorists) because of its analytic properties, but would not be used in such cases.
